# What will be the value of resultSet2 if query executed successfully or not

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

```
preparedStatement2 = connect2.prepareStatement("select regno from student where regno= "
                        + ""+Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText())+"");
resultSet2 = preparedStatement2.executeQuery();
```

This is my code to execute a SQL query. If the query executed successfully, that is if 'regno' is found in the table, what will be the value of 'resultSet2' ? Also if 'regno' is not found, what will be the value of 'resultSet2' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 of three things will happen:

1. You will have a resultset filled with data (successful run with data)
2. You will have an empty resultset (no data, but successful run)
3. An exception will be thrown, so the resultset will not get filled at all. (problem with connection or bad query)

To get the data:

```
while (resultSet2.next()) {
        String regno = rs.getString("reg");
        // DO something with regno
}
```

The nice thing is that even if resultSet2 is empty, the while statement will resolve as false and not run.

Check here for more info:

[Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: Thanks for your information. How can I identify what value is stored in resultSet2 ?